# Reasons behind the choice of 172.16/192.168?

Tags: networking, protocols

It is a known fact that there are three blocks of IPv4 Addresses that were chosen to be reserved for private networks:

```
 10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
 172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
 192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

(as specified by [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)). However, although I can sort of see why 10.0.0.0 would be a natural choice, I can think of no particular reason why 172.16.0.0 and 192.168.0.0 were chosen among all the possibilities. I tried to google about this but got nothing, and the RFC document did not provide any explanation either. Was it really just a random decision?

Comment: Why? Why would `10.0.0.0` be a natural choice?

Comment: FYI: that [tag:history] tag says: _"DO NOT USE - Removed as part of "The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012" - See link in Tag Wiki for more information."_

Comment: K-ballo: Thought 10 was a low number that was maybe more likely to be chosen (plus the fact that we use decimal numbers in everyday life). But I guess the real reason is what Sahu provided below.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

AS stated by ganeshh.iyer "

> 10.0.0.0/8 was the old ARPANET, which they picked up on 01-Jan-1983. When they shut down the ARPANET in 1990, the 10.0.0.0/8 block was freed. There was much argument about if there should ever be private IP spaces, given that a goal of IPv4 was universal to all hosts on the net.
>
> In then end, practicality won out, and RFC 1597 reserved the now well known private address spaces. When ARPANET went away, the 10.0.0.0/8 allocation was marked as reserved and since it was known that the ARPANET was truly gone (the hosts being moved to MILNET, NSFNET or the Internet) it was decided that this was the best Class A block to allocate.
>
> Note Class A. This was before CIDR. So, the Class A, B and C private address netblocks needed to come out of the correct IP ranges.
>
> I know that 172.16.0.0/12 was picked because it offered the most continuous block of Class B (/16) addresses in the IP space that was in a reserved block. 192.0.0.0/24 was always reserved for the same reason that 0.0.0.0/8 and 128.0.0.0/16 were reserved (first blocks of the old Class C, A and B network blocks) so assigning 192.168.0.0/24 out as private fit well -- 192.0.2.0/24 was already TEST-NET, where you could use them in public documentation without fear of someone trying it (see example.com for another example.)"

Quoted from:

- https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2014967
- https://supportforums.cisco.com/people/ganeshh.iyer

Comment: When you lift entire posts, especially ones that say things like 'I know that ...', it is your duty to make it clear that you are in fact quoting somebody else.

Comment: Sorry EJP i have edited it and given the courtesy.
However i have given the link to the post.